# Kafka producer writing file to topic: TimeoutException: Expiring record(s), Error sending message to topic with key: null, value

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a file to a kafka topic through the kafka-producer cli using this command

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic foo < output
```

where I pipe in the file. Each row in the file has been tested on my local kafka instance and this command works. The issue is when I VPN into my remote testing environment and run the same command I get the below errors (thousands of times) and about 70k out of 870k records make it to the consumer on that VPN environment.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 30 record(s) for foo-1: 1546 ms has passed since last append
ERROR Error when sending message to topic foo with key: null, value: 545 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

I've attempted raising the time out and batch size by adding flags to improve throughput but there's not much difference in the number of messages going through (will need to do more testing)

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --timeout 30000 -request-required-acks 1 --batch-size 100000 --topic foo < output
```

Comment: You'd better increase the request timeout by adding `--request-timeout-ms ****` and retry.

Comment: Were you able to figure this problem out?  I'm running into something similar right now, but it only happens when brokers rejoin the cluster.